# Galois theory: Permutation of zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am new to Galois theory and while learning I got stuck analysing the following example:

We consider 
$$f: (x^2-2)(x^2-3) \in \mathbb{Q}[x].$$

The splitting field is $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois field we know that 
$$|\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})| = [L : \mathbb{Q}] = 4.$$

So far so good. Now I'm getting confused: The example states, that each $\phi \in \operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ need to permute the zeros of $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$, that means $\phi(\sqrt{2}) = \pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\phi(\sqrt{3}) = \pm \sqrt{3}$. That yields to four possibilities and we go on showing that $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong Z_2 \times Z_2$.

Why are these the only possibilities for $\phi$. Why - for example - is 
$$\phi:  \sqrt{2} \to -\sqrt{3},  \sqrt{3} \to -\sqrt{2}$$
not allowed? What's the reason for being restricted only on permutations of the zeros of the factors $x^2-2$ and $x^2-3$?

Comment: $\phi$ would map $2$ to $3$ and therefore not fix $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ok, I get that. We have $2 = \phi(2) = \phi(\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}) = -\sqrt{3} \cdot (-\sqrt{3}) = 3$. So in general: Do I always just consider permutations of the factorised polynom?

Comment: The verb is "permute" (not "permutate").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha \in L$ and $p(\alpha)=0$ with $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, then $\phi(\alpha)$ must a root of $p(x)$ because $p(\phi(\alpha))=\phi(p(\alpha))=0$, since $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Take $\alpha=\sqrt2$. Then $\phi(\alpha)$ must be a root of $p(x)=x^2-2$ and so can only be $\pm \sqrt 2$; it cannot be $\pm \sqrt 3$.